# Scala 2.11.2 ScriptEngine is Null for .getEngineByName("scala")

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scriptengine, scala-2.11

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Scala Worksheet. (Scala 2.11.2)

I'm trying to get ScriptEngine for Scala.

```
val e = (new ScriptEngineManager()).getEngineByName("scala")
```

But I get `null`:

```
e: javax.script.ScriptEngine = null
```

How can I get Scala ScriptEngine in Scala Worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly there is a bug in IDEA Scala plugin. In order to make it work, first of all, you need to add scala-compiler library to Dependencies, since the SPI is in scala-compiler.jar. Secondly, uncheck "Run worksheet in the compiler process" in IDEA Preferences. I guess scala-compiler.jar is not in the classpath when external compiler is started.